# Evaluate Expression LLDB Python C++ Type Formatter

Tags: python, c++, formatting, lldb

I'm trying to make an lldb custom type formatter for a variant type, but I can't seem to call a query member function on the value to format. I have a size_t member called typeIndex, that can be gotten by calling index(). I can get the value by getting it directly through the get child member with name, but I can't seem to call the index() function which directly returns that value. What do I have to do to call a function on the type being formatted?

```
def format_variant(valobj, internal_dict):
    a = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName("typeIndex").GetValueAsUnsigned()
    b = valobj.EvaluateExpression(".index()").GetValueAsUnsigned()
    
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

b always results in no value, a is fine.

Comment: Why isn't there a Python tag on this question? And why is there a C++ tag when your question has nothing to do with C++ and contains only Python code?

Comment: I think OP is debugging a C++ app, and scripting the LLDB debugger using its built-in Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You want to eval "index()" instead of ".index()"